# Как правильно настроить HelmetJS?

Tags: node.js, express

Как правильно настроить Helmet?

Я его подключил просто вот так:

```
app.use(helmet());
```

Но из-за него перестали показываться изображения, которые выводились просто по ссылке

Например: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Node.js_logo.svg/1200px-Node.js_logo.svg.png

Пример ошибки:
[image: Пример ошибки]

Я пытался погуглить ошибку и настройки Hemlet, но так ничего и не нашёл, а то что нашёл не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял в чём проблема, только задал вопрос и сразу понял)

По умолчанию одна из настроек, которая отвечает за изображения выглядит так:

```
   helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
     directives: {
        "img-src": ["'self'", "data:"]
     },
  },
})
```

Нужно исправить просто на это:

```
   helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
     directives: {
        ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
        "img-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
     },
  },
 })
```